# CSS Sourcemaps not loaded

Tags: css, sass, source-maps, gulp-sourcemaps

So I have the following task:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src(['./angular/app/**/*.s+(a|c)ss'])
        .pipe($.concat('app.css'))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe($.sass({  includePaths: ['./angular/app/global'] }).on('error', $.sass.logError))
            .pipe($.if(gulpUtil.env.env === 'prod', $.uglify().on('error', onError)))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('./'))

        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'))
        .pipe($.notify({
            title: 'Gulp',
            subtitle: 'success',
            message: 'sass compiled',
            sound: "Pop"
        }))
        .pipe($.livereload());
});
```

this works like it should, and it a generates map file next to the css file.
In the css file the bottom line is the following:

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=app.css.map */
```

but chrome nor Firefox loads in that map file. Am I doing something wrong? or is there something not working?

Altough the JS files with a similar task does split up the js in the souces tab in my devTools

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it was a conflict with the concat.

so fixed it via:

```
var prefix = function () {
    var prefix = new Buffer("\n/* Added dynamically */\n", 'utf-8');

    return through.obj(function(file, enc, cb) {
        file.contents = Buffer.concat([prefix, file.contents]);
        this.push(file);
        cb();
    });
};

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src(['./angular/app/**/*.s+(a|c)ss'])
        .pipe(prefix())
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe($.sass({  includePaths: ['./angular/app/global']}).on('error', $.sass.logError))
            .pipe($.if(gulpUtil.env.env === 'prod', $.uglify().on('error', onError)))
        .pipe($.concat('app.css'))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'))
        .pipe($.notify({
            title: 'Gulp',
            subtitle: 'success',
            message: 'sass compiled',
            sound: "Pop"
        }))
        .pipe($.livereload());
});
```

Only issue I now have is that the source maps can't be in a different file.